# why is the ansible sros_command module responding with an error from a role, but works independently

Tags: ansible, python-module

I am attempting to send a command to an SROS device using an ansible role.  The task itself is:

```
- name: invoke the sros cli
  sros_command:
    commands: ["{{item.input}}"]  
  register: sros_command_result
```

This command is being run inside a loop of several commands.  I know that the module will allow you to send multiple commands at once, but I need to do additional processing on each command so its simpler to handle them individually.  I've verified that item.input is correct, and the notation is sending the command as a list which is what the module wants for input.

In the case I am testing the command itself is `show chassis`.

I have verified that I am connected to the device, and an independent debug run of the module only generates the correct response from the device.

When I run this via my role though, it response with: `"Unable to decode JSON from response to exec_command('{\"command\": \"show chassis\", \"prompt\": null, \"answer\": null}'). Received 'None'."`

Im very lost.  I do not know why this error is appearing (other than the device not sending a response), nor can I figure out any way to debug this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try with:
gather_facts: false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).